# Bouncy Castle vs Java default RSA with OAEP

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, jce

Can someone explain to me why this code throws `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error` on the final line when it's decrypting the key?

```
// Given an RSA key pair...
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

// ... and an AES key:
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(256);
SecretKey aesKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

// When I encrypt the key with this Bouncy Castle cipher:
Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encryptedKey = encryptionCipher.doFinal(aesKey.getEncoded());

// Then trying to decrypt the key with this cipher...
Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
// ... throws `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error` here:
decryptionCipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
```

Is the following statement from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886397/66722 also true for RSA with OAEP?

> "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" actually doesn't implement ECB mode encryption.
>   It should have been called "RSA/None/PKCS1Padding" as it can only be
>   used to encrypt a single block of plaintext (or, indeed a secret key).
>   This is just a naming mistake of Sun/Oracle.

If so, I would expect these transformations to be equivalent and my test above to pass. The same padding has been specified in both, so why the `BadPaddingException`?

Either way, I would appreciate a layman's explanation of what the difference is.

Comment: Those transformations are equivalent. There is no "mode" of RSA, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For similar Stackoverflow questions with more information please see [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33572909/238704) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32161720/238704).

The "mode" part of the transformation string has no effect. The problem is different defaults used by different providers. This is unfortunate and very definitely suboptimal. Should we blame Sun/Oracle? I have no opinion beyond being dissatisfied with the result.

OAEP is a fairly complicated construction with two different hash functions as parameters. The Cipher transform string lets you specify one of these, which you have specified as SHA-256. However, the MGF1 function also is parameterized by a hash function which you cannot specify in the cipher transformation string. The Oracle provider defaults to SHA1 whereas the BouncyCastle provider defaults to SHA-256. So, in effect, there is a hidden parameter that is critical for interoperability.

The solution is to specify more fully what these hidden parameters are by supplying an [`OAEPParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.html) to the `Cipher.init(...)` method as in the following example:

```
Cipher encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA256AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1",
                MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpec);
// ...
// ...
// ...
Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1",
                MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, oaepParameterSpec);
```

The first one is effectively a no-op, because those are already the defaults for Bouncycastle.

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thanks. Are you able to point me to the evidence of this statement: "The Oracle provider defaults to SHA1 whereas the BouncyCastle provider defaults to SHA-256."? I'm curious to figure out how I could have discovered this myself - it's hard to follow the implementations hidden behind those magic transformation strings.

Comment: @MartinDow: No, I can't find where it says that. Because I suspected it, I was able to step through the code with a debugger into the sun.* classes and see it. Oracle/Sun tend to be as standards-compliant as they can, and it is kind of implied I think in [PKCS#1, section A.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.1) where is says `maskGenAlgorithm   [1] MaskGenAlgorithm  DEFAULT mgf1SHA1`.