# x509Certificate to RsaKeyParameters for encrypt data

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to encrypt data with BouncyCastle in VB so i take for reference this answer [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489992/how-do-i-use-bouncy-castle-in-net-to-encrypt-using-rsa-ecb-oaepwithsha256andmgf/56497097#56497097) and have something like this:

```
        Dim cerReader = New PemReader(File.OpenText("the\route\certificate.cer"))
        Dim rsaPub = CType(cerReader.ReadObject(), Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters)
        Dim encrypter = New OaepEncoding(New RsaEngine(), New Sha256Digest(), New Sha256Digest(), Nothing)
        encrypter.Init(True, rsaPub)
        Dim cipher = encrypter.ProcessBlock(data, 0, data.Length)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(cipher)
```

but in the line:

> Dim rsaPub = CType(cerReader.ReadObject(), Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters)

gives me this error:

> Cannot cast an object of type 'Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate' to type 'Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters'.

and i can't found in the docs some example o make that cast or encrypt using .cer just .pem that i think is the same but doesn't work. Someone have a idea of what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension .cer is ambiguous, sometimes it means a PEM encoded, sometimes a DER encoded certificate. Since you are applying a `PemReader` I assume you are using a PEM encoded certificate.
On the linked site a PEM encoded public key is imported, while here a certificate is imported. For this the second line has to be replaced by:

```vb
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.X509
...
Dim rsaPub = DirectCast(cerReader.ReadObject(), X509Certificate).GetPublicKey()
```

With this the `PemReader` imports an `X509Certificate` whose public key is fetched with `GetPublicKey()`. The rest of the code does not need to be changed.

Comment: Yes it is a PEM enconded certificate and works excellent, thanks for something new i learned :)