# Encrypt in Java using RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding, decrypt in c# using OAEPSHA256 Padding

Tags: c#, encryption, sha256

I have a situation where a Java program encrypts text using RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding.

I need to decrypt it in c#.

Encryption and decryption work fine in Java.

Encryption in Java and decryption in c# with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding works absolutely fine.

However, with RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding encryption in Java and decryption with OaepSHA256 in C# gives me the error : The parameter is incorrect.

Java Code for encrypt:

```
public static String encrypt(KeyPair keypair, String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
        //Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keypair.getPublic());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(c.doFinal(data.getBytes()));
    }
```

C # code for decrypt :

```
public string DecryptRsa(byte[] encryptedBytes, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2, RSAEncryptionPadding rSAEncryptionPadding)
        {
            var text = string.Empty;

            using (RSACng csp = (RSACng)x509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey())
            {

                byte[] bytesDecrypted = csp.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, rSAEncryptionPadding);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
            }
            return text;
        }
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OAEP uses two digests, the OAEP digest and the MGF1 digest, see [RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1).

The SunJCE provider specifies with `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` the OAEP digest as SHA256, while the MGF1 digest defaults to SHA1, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299291). The C# code, on the other hand, specifies with `OaepSHA256` both digests as SHA256. Therefore, both codes are incompatible.

The fix is to either explicitly specify the digests in Java with [`OAEPParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/spec/OAEPParameterSpec.html) (which should always be done anyway for this very reason). On the C# side, no fix is possible with on board means, since a separate specification of both digests is not supported. But BouncyCastle can be used which supports this.

---

Fix, Java code side (SHA256 for both digests):

```java
RSAPublicKey publicKey = ...
OAEPParameterSpec oaepParameterSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParameterSpec);
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
```

Fix, C# code side, using BouncyCastle (SHA256 for OAEP digest, SHA1 for MGF1 digest):

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Encodings;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
...
RsaKeyParameters privateKey = ...
OaepEncoding oaepEncoding = new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha256Digest(), new Sha1Digest(), null);
oaepEncoding.Init(false, privateKey);
byte[] decrypted = oaepEncoding.ProcessBlock(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, I do not have any control over the Java code as it's third party code calling my API using my public key for encryption. I tried using BouncyCastle. Exactly the same code as suggested by you above. It gives me a very cryptic "data wrong" error.

Comment: I am sorry. When I said I did use BouncyCastle I used Sha256Digest for both digests to initialize OaepEncoding. Will try with the other hash as you suggested. Thanks very much.

Comment: This works with my Java/C# Encryption/Decryption (Which was not working earlier.). So i willl mark this as answer. However the third party encrypted string still throws "data wrong" error in BouncyCastle C#. Must be something wrong with what they are doing @ encryption.

Comment: Great answer. I had to implement a .NET version of `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING` which ended up being `new OaepEncoding(new RsaEngine(), new Sha512Digest(), new Sha1Digest(), null);`.